# What are the chances of life on 7 Earth-like exoplanets discovered by NASA?

Tags: nasa, exoplanet, trappist-1

NASA has announced the discovery of 7 Earth-like exoplanets 13 hours ago. **What are the chances of life there**? Is it possible to see the ground of these planets from here? How far are they?

Comment: *"What are the chances of life on 7 earth like exoplanets discovered by NASA?"* Between 0 and 1 out of 1. Narrowing it down further would be pure speculation at the moment.

Comment: *"Also how far they are?"* A Google search on 'NASA has discovered 7 earth like exoplanet' suggests they're orbiting a star at a distance of 40 LY.

Comment: @AndrewThompson So Does it mean the planet we are looking at is 40 years in past?

Comment: There is insufficient data to make any determination at this point @Rishi.

Comment: So do they use "Transit photometry" to find exo planets, it seems using Transit photometry one is only shooting in the Dark (means what we can possibly know is only the size of planet)

Comment: With [transit photometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_detecting_exoplanets#Transit_photometry), it may also be possible to gain informations about a planet's atmosphere. So future observations could give us indications about whether a planet in the habitable zone actually has an atmosphere that may be suitable for life or not.

Comment: @DarkDust Like in Kepler series, they found some in habitable zone, So now can we do something about it, Kepler was 500 LY, And we can not do something about then what is the point as said by C. Towne Springer in answer

Comment: To the close voters: it's too early to decisively answer this question, but that doesn't make it a bad question (and I have a feeling lots of people will be wondering about it). Perhaps we could add an answer about *how* we would determine whether the exoplanets had life, which could then be edited when studies become available.

Comment: *"To the close voters: it's too early to decisively answer this question, but that doesn't make it a bad question (and I have a feeling lots of people will be wondering about it)."* That's what down-votes are for, and so far, this question has no down votes. Close votes are for a variety of different reasons.

Answer (score 3):

NASA has said roughly Earth sized. From this, reporters have written "Earth like". Some publications are even showing what look like photos of planets. These are likely generated with computers used for creating planets in games and films.

As for life, we only know of one planet that developed life, and you can't build a statistical model from that. Searching for life could be a complete waste of time.

Comment: Kepler-186f's location is within the habitable zone

Comment: What about liquid water?

Comment: @Rishi all the habitable zone means is that if a range of necessary conditions are met, water could exist on a body in the habitable zone. What are those conditions, then? An atmosphere that provides the pressure without which water cannot stay liquid (but the atmosphere can't be too thick because then we get a runaway greenhouse effect which is what probably happened on Venus), a magnetic field that slows down the rate at which water is lost to space when the sun splits water molecules into hydrogen (lost to space because they are so light) and oxygen atoms... And so on

Comment: i think the likelihood hearing SETI messages from any **particular** planet or solar system is very very low, but if the Strong Anthropic Principle is true, it might be that if some random planet happens to have a sun like ours (that will last 10^10 years) and is about 10^8 km away and has the elemental and chemical diversity of Earth, that it might be that, after a few billion years, life has little choice but to emerge.  but it could stay as algae-like goop and not evolve to sentient and sapient beings asking questions like we are.